# Rails - partial locals not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

When I try to render a partial in an AJAX response it's saying `undefined local variable or method 'campaign'`

In `create.js.erb`:

`$("#progress").html("<%= j(render 'campaigns/progress_bars', locals: {campaign: @bid.campaign}) %>");`

And then whenever I refer to it in the partial I just use something like:

`<%= campaign.option_1 unless campaign.blank? %>`

I use this partial elsewhere in the app and it works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it's necessary to use the `partial` keyword in this scenario:

`$("#progress").html("<%= j(render partial: 'campaigns/progress_bars', locals: {campaign: @bid.campaign}) %>");`

I'm still not sure when and why that is necessary but it was the fix for this problem.

Comment: Thanks for this, this sure is a puzzling one. I'm going to look for an issue open on GitHub.